# Get the Immediate Category than contains a product by its ID

Tags: product, category, collection

Assuming that each product can only be assigned to no more than 1 category, how would I retrieve the category's ID by using the known Product's ID?
I would also like to list all IDs within a Category from the known Category ID.

Case 1:

Category_? -> Product_with_ID_34

Category_? -> Product_with_ID_12

Category_? -> Product_with_ID_08
Get immediate containing category of the known product ID

Case 2:

Category_with_ID_1 ->

```
           Show ID of all products listed in this category
```

Category_with_ID_2 ->

```
           Show ID of all products listed in this category
```

Category_with_ID_3 ->

```
           Show ID of all products listed in this category
```

EDIT:
Of course a category can contain more than 1 product

Comment: Its worth noting that what I'm trying to achieve is to create a json file that contains: Category_ID -> Product_ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I've understood your question, but both methods are provided by Magento objects. I asume you know how to load catalog objects by ID in Magento

**Get CategoryIds of a product**

```
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

**Get ProductIds of a category**

```
$productIds = $category->getProductCollection()->getAllIds();
```